# How to run code type-checked python code using Pyright?

Tags: python, pyright

I have installed Pyright for type-checking my Python code, but I am not sure how to run it. For example, this is the code I have

```py
def add(x: int, y: int):
    return x + y


print(add(10, 20))
```

When I try to run it with `python`, `python typed.py`, it gives me the following errors:

```
  File "typed.py", line 2
    def add(x: int, y: int):
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have run through the doc, but I have found no option for compiling or running the code. How can I run these typed Python code?

Comment: Which Python version are you running?

Comment: Are u run the code by Python2?

Comment: @pepper, not necessarily. Type hinting was introduced from Python 3.5 so any version prior to 3.5 would cause issues.

Comment: Oh If I run the code with `Python3.9` it is working. @pavel thank you for the hints.

Comment: Type hints were introduced in Python 3.5. Earlier versions do not recognize them and report a syntax error. You are apparently trying to run this code in a Python 2 interpreter.